# Can Spring's ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean work with generics that refer to interfaces?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring's ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean to retrieve a prototype scoped bean, as described in the [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean.html). Below is my applicationContext.

```
<bean id="exportFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName">
        <idref local="export" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="export" class="com.someorg.ExportImpl" scope="prototype"/>
```

I autowire the *exportFactory* into a class like so:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("exportFactory")
private ObjectFactory<?> exportFactory;
```

<strike>And this works as expected. Each call to the *exportFactory.getObject()* method returns a new *ExportImpl*</strike>. On further inspect, a call to getObject() actually returns the following instance: **org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean$TargetBeanObjectFactory**

Now, *ExportImpl* is an implementation of an *Export* interface. And when I attempt to to declare the *exportFactory* using generics, described below, I get an exception.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("exportFactory")
private ObjectFactory<Export> exportFactory;
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.someorg.Export] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=exportFactory)}
```

The application context successfully loads with this configuration, and the exception is thrown when I call *exportFactory.getObject()*. Using the same configuration I can successfully retrieve an instance of ExportImpl, so I know that bean is correctly wired.

I'd like to know a) what is Spring doing here and b) is there a reason I'm unable to use an ObjectFactory with type parameter that's an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean` is not necessary when you obtain `ObjectFactory` via `@Autowired`. In this case `ObjectFactory` for your bean is created automatically, though I can't find any reference of this behaviour in the documentation.

So, the behaviour you observe can be explained as follows:

- When you write `@Autowired @Qualifier("exportFactory") ObjectFactory<?>`, Spring creates `ObjectFactory` that returns a bean named `exportFactory`, which itself is an `ObjectFactory` returned by the `ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean` (its class is `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean$TargetBeanObjectFactory`).
- When you write `@Autowired @Qualifier("exportFactory") ObjectFactory<Export>`, Spring tries to find bean of type `Export` named `exportFactory`, and the search fails.

Comment: This would explain why my call to exportFactory().getObject() was returning an instance of ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean$TargetBeanObjectFactory, which would then, upon casting, return the expected ExportImpl.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I had the spring-context-2.5.xsd, and the spring-beans-2.5.xsd while running spring-3.0.2. I changed the schema locations to 3.0, and the problem went away.

Comment: And yes, commenting out the bean with id="exportFactory" has also done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @axtavt - If you use the @Qualifier describing by Bozho, you can retain @Autowired and Spring in fact returns the expected bean.

Comment: @unsquared: Yes, because in this case Spring looks for the bean of type `Export` named `export`, and successfully finds it, ignoring the unnecessary `exportFactory`.

Comment: @axtavt - Yup. It is a bit counter-intuitive though. Would @Resource("exportFactory") work? I'm going to test that out.

Answer (score 1):

Change the qualifier to:

```
@Qualifier("export")
```

Comment: Yeah, that was just me simplifying and forgetting to change my pasted code. The working code has the correct qualifier.

Comment: @unsquared - no, your exception tells otherwise - `Qualifier(value=exportFactory)}`

Comment: @Bozho, I was copying and pasting into notepad, before posting to SO. I changed the value in the xml and stacktrace, but forgot the qualifier.

Comment: @unsquared - well, it is working for me with the correct qualifier. So double-check that you've had the correct qualifier, and give the corresponding exception message

Comment: @Bozho, indeed you're right. Stupid mistake. I've accepted axtavt's answer because this won't help anybody who is less brain dead than me, and deals with an interesting Spring feature.

Comment: @Bozho, ah, this answer is also correct and interesting. Can I accept both?

Comment: @unsquared you can't accept both. Let axtavt's be accepted - he gives more insight into the problem. Or perhaps provide your own answer, stating that changing the schema fixed the problem, and accept it.